# MySQL 8.0 docker container always restarting Error just show [note]

Tags: docker, containers, google-compute-engine

I've search for a similar problem as mine but no luck haven't found a good solution for it,
 after I've just created Ubuntu 18.04 vm and then ran mydocker in GCE with static IP , 
 Every service worked fine, except the MySQL container is always on restarting status.

```
just saw [Note] [Entrypoint] blah..blah.. NO ERROR LOG MSG (see output)
```

version: "3.7"

```
services:
.....

  database:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql80
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mydb/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mydb/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ./logs/mysql:/var/log/mysql
    env_file:
      - ./mydb/.env
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
.....
```

mysql 8.0 show status: Restarting 
docker ps

```
e496acc7e5e8        nginx:1.17.8            "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   40 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes                  0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp         nginx1178
2244963e6b70        testings_php             "docker-php-entrypoi…"   40 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes                  0.0.0.0:32771->9000/tcp    php74
5f6199478657        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   40 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes                  0.0.0.0:8888->80/tcp       phpmyadmin
7e0e25a6a099        mysql:8.0               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   41 minutes ago   Restarting (1) 45 seconds ago                          mysql80
```

mysql 8.0 container logs   
output:

```
2020-03-16 14:49:02+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-03-16 14:49:03+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-03-16 14:49:03+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-03-16 14:49:12+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-03-16 14:49:13+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-03-16 14:49:13+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-03-16 14:49:18+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-03-16 14:49:18+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-03-16 14:49:18+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-03-16 14:49:23+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-03-16 14:49:24+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-03-16 14:49:24+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-03-16 14:49:30+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-03-16 14:49:30+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-03-16 14:49:30+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-03-16 14:49:36+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-03-16 14:49:37+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-03-16 14:49:37+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-03-16 14:49:45+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-03-16 14:49:45+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-03-16 14:49:45+07:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
```

my.cnf

```
[mysql]
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
basedir                         = /usr
bind_address                    = 127.0.0.1 # Change to 0.0.0.0 to allow remote connections
datadir                         = /var/lib/mysql
max_allowed_packet              = 256M
max_connect_errors              = 10000
pid_file                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
port                            = 3306
skip_external_locking
skip_name_resolve
socket                          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld`12w3sedx.sock

secure-file-priv= NULL
symbolic-links=0

tmpdir                          = /tmp
user                            = mysql

# InnoDB Settings
default_storage_engine          = InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 2     
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 1G   
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 64M
innodb_log_file_size            = 512M
innodb_stats_on_metadata        = 0

innodb_read_io_threads          = 64
innodb_write_io_threads         = 64

key_buffer_size                 = 1024M  

low_priority_updates            = 1
concurrent_insert               = 2

# Connection Settings
max_connections                 = 500   

back_log                        = 512
thread_cache_size               = 100
thread_stack                    = 192K

interactive_timeout             = 180
wait_timeout                    = 180

# Buffer Settings
join_buffer_size                = 4M    
read_buffer_size                = 3M    
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 4M    
sort_buffer_size                = 4M    

table_definition_cache          = 8192
table_open_cache                = 8192  
open_files_limit                = 16000 
                                     
max_heap_table_size             = 128M
tmp_table_size                  = 128M

# Search Settings
ft_min_word_len                 = 3    

# Logging
log_error                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql_error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes   = 1
long_query_time                 = 5
slow_query_log                  = 0   
slow_query_log_file             = /var/lib/mysql/mysql_slow.log

[mysqldump]
quick
quote_names
max_allowed_packet              = 64M

innodb_use_native_aio = 0
```

Any workaround ? thank you

Comment: Does removing the bind mount of the `my.cnf` file help it start up, at least?  That would narrow things down.  (I don't think it would prevent startup, but you do need to change `bind_address = 0.0.0.0`: in a Docker context "remote" means "anything outside the database container", including other containers.)

Comment: btw: thx @ David Maze   i've fixed this issue by remove all image and then run again.